# Lenovo Y510p - SSD not showing up

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-10-upgrade

Today I decided to format my computer (Lenovo y510P - 59406636 dual nVidia) to clean things up and to try the Windows 10.
Everything went alright, I installed using an UEFI bootable pendrive.

After the installation, I noticed that my SSD wasn't there anymore. Before formatting, I had 1 partition with my 1TB (st1000lm014-sshd-8gb) and another with my Lenovo 24GB ssd that contains a folder with the drivers.

I tried everything, and it does not show in the BIOS neither the Disk Management.

I have no idea what is happening, if anyone could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Here you go: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y510p-SSD/td-p/1306563

Comment: But what I mean is that I was able to see before formatting. And now it shows nothing, neither in the Disk Management. Should I create a new partition and set as cache?. Using the SeaTools it says that the cache is enabled, but I stil can't see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My M.2 SSD has disappeared from my ideapad Y510p](https://superuser.com/questions/1024268/my-m-2-ssd-has-disappeared-from-my-ideapad-y510p)