# My M.2 SSD has disappeared from my ideapad Y510p

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, lenovo-laptop, hard-drive-cache

I have a Lenovo ideapad Y510p running Windows 10. The other day, I had to power it off by holding down the power button. Since then, my LITEONIT LSS-24L6G SSD cache has disappeared from my system. I can't see it in Disk Manager nor from running diskpart. If I run ExpressCache with the command "eccmd -info", I get the message "HFS volume is not mounted".

I have tried several solutions from the links below, including running power cycles with and without the SSD connected, and also putting the computer to sleep and boot up again. Unfortunately, nothing has made the SSD appear again.

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/disappearing-ssd-syndrome.175417/
http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Crucial-SSDs/Why-did-my-SSD-quot-disappear-quot-from-my-system/ta-p/65215 (though it is another manufacturer of the SSD, the problem sounded very similar)
https://www.techinferno.com/index.php?/forums/topic/6115-y510p-m2-ssd-disappearing/&page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I don't know if it's something I would recommend, since I guess there might be some risk.

After losing my patience, I decided to unplug and plug in the SSD while having the laptop running. Surprisingly, this worked and the SSD was immediately recognized by the system and ExpressCache was working again after a reboot.